# Updating data-text dynamically for twitter button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I am working on a random quote generator and would like to have my twitter button's data-text update itself when my "newQuote" button is pressed.

When I click the newQuote button, my page displays the randomly selected quote. I would like it so the twitter button tweets the current random quote displayed.

It works the first time I press on the newQuote button, but after that, the twitter button doesn't update itself.

HTML:

```
<button type = "button" id ="newQuote">
New Quote  
</button>

<div>
<a id = "twitter-button"></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 var quotes = [
  "Circumstances-what are circumstances? I make circumstances",
  "Life isn't about finding yourself. Life is about creating yourself.",
  "Worry is a misuse of the imagination",

];

var authors = [
  "Napolean",
  "George Bernard Shaw",
  "Dan Zadra",

];

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("newQuote").onclick = function() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = quotes[random];
    document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = authors[random];
    createButton();
  }  
  }

function createButton() { 
      var msg = document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML;
      var tweetDiv = document.getElementById("twitter-button");
      var link = document.createElement("a");

      link.setAttribute("href", "https://twitter.com/share");
      link.setAttribute("class", "twitter-share-button");
      link.setAttribute('id', 'twitter');
      link.setAttribute("data-text", "" + msg + "");
      link.setAttribute("data-size", "large");
      tweetDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(link, tweetDiv);
      twttr.widgets.load();
}


! function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
  if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }
}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an anchor with the ID `twitter-button`.

But as soon as you load the Twitter Widget, it replaces that anchor with an `iframe` that doesn't have that ID, so your code stops working. The way to solve this, is by changing that anchor to use a CSS class `twitter-share-button`, because the generated `iframe` also has this class attached to it.

Then, instead of doing:

```
// HTML
<a id = "twitter-button"></a>
// CSS
var tweetDiv = document.getElementById("twitter-button");
```

You change that to:

```
// HTML
<a class="twitter-share-button"></a>
// JS
var tweetDiv = document.querySelector(".twitter-share-button");
```

Take a look at the example below:

```html
<button type="button" id="newQuote">
  New Quote
</button>

<div>
  <div id="quote"></div>
  <div id="author"></div>
  <a class="twitter-share-button"></a>
</div>

<script>
  var quotes = [
    "Circumstances-what are circumstances? I make circumstances",
    "Life isn't about finding yourself. Life is about creating yourself.",
    "Worry is a misuse of the imagination",

  ];

  var authors = [
    "Napolean",
    "George Bernard Shaw",
    "Dan Zadra",

  ];

  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("newQuote").onclick = function() {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = quotes[random];
      document.getElementById("author").innerHTML = authors[random];
      createButton();
    }
  }

  function createButton() {
    var msg = document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML;
    var tweetDiv = document.querySelector(".twitter-share-button");
    var link = document.createElement("a");

    link.setAttribute("href", "https://twitter.com/share");
    link.setAttribute("class", "twitter-share-button");
    link.setAttribute('id', 'twitter');
    link.setAttribute("data-text", "" + msg + "");
    link.setAttribute("data-size", "large");
    tweetDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(link, tweetDiv);
    twttr.widgets.load();
  }


  ! function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }
  }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the parent element on first time on next time you can't get `twitter-button` id

Update your function like this

```
function createButton() { 
      var msg = document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML;
      if(document.getElementById("twitter").length)
      return      document.getElementById("twitter").setAttribute("data-text",msg);
      var tweetDiv = document.getElementById("twitter-button");
      var link = document.createElement("a");

      link.setAttribute("href", "https://twitter.com/share");
      link.setAttribute("class", "twitter-share-button");
      link.setAttribute('id', 'twitter');
      link.setAttribute("data-text", "" + msg + "");
      link.setAttribute("data-size", "large");
      tweetDiv.parentNode.replaceChild(link, tweetDiv);
      twttr.widgets.load();
}
```